# Bus stops at Ottawa University

Tags: buses, montreal, ottawa

I'm traveling Montreal-Ottawa 3 Oct, (Horaire 5814) and I need take off of the bus at Ottawa University, does the bus stop there, or I have to inform to the driver in advance?

Comment: What bus company?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, [Greyhound](http://extranet.greyhound.com/Revsup/csked2/pdf/782c.pdf) 5814 will not stop at Ottawa University, the 5804, 5806, 5808, 5812, 5816, 5820, 5822, 5824, 5826, 5830, 5832, 5844 and 5846 all have a stop at Laurier and Cumberland, right across from the University.

[image: bus schedule comparison]